# Axis2 Change the default service port

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, apache-axis

Is there any way to override the axis default port specified in axis2.xml through code?

I want to initialize it with a dynamic value, keeping all other settings intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `AxisServletListener#setPort(int)`

Read javadoc here:

http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/transport/http/AxisServletListener.html#setPort(int)

Comment: Thank You.
Could you please tell how can I use the above. Currently I am trying to override the AxisServlet to create a custom class. Is this approach correct?

Comment: I don't think you need to override AxisServlet, see no reason. You should just call `#setPort` of default `AxisServlet`.

Comment: but, from where will I call this method?

Comment: whenever you wanna change the port :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change anything at runtime using 
[`AxisConfiguration`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/engine/AxisConfiguration.html) and [`ConfigurationContext`](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/api/org/apache/axis2/context/ConfigurationContext.html).